# https://stackoverflow.com redirects to http://stackoverflow.com/ui/ti/welcomePage

Tags: support, homepage

I just updated to Chrome v. **53.0.2785.116 m**

Navigating to https://stackoverflow.com/ it redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/ui/ti/welcomePage displaying the *"404 Not found"* page, what's going on? Is this a sort of bug/new buggy-feature?

I checked my userscripts and none of them is doing this (I disabled them all and it still happens)

Comment: Did you also disable extensions? Maybe one of them is causing it. Does it happen on other browsers, or just Chrome? I can't reproduce it on same Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Chrome v 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1...

Comment: Nor can I reproduce on Chrome v 53.0.2785.116 m with Windows 7.  I also cannot reproduce this in Incognito mode (to simulate a user not being logged in)

Comment: Nope, this happens only in Chrome normal mode (not incognito), I disabled all my extensions and it still happens, tomorrow I will try to reinstall Chrome and see what happens

Comment: No repro, IE 6/win98

Comment: Lots of hits for ui/ti/welcomepage, but not much good info about where it's coming from.

Comment: No repro in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m (same version), Windows 10.

Comment: I get mostly Italian search results for `ui/ti/welcomePage`, might be a clue. Can you check the headers of the response that causes the redirect? Might have some useful info in there.

Comment: What if you go to the https url ? (no repro for me either).

Comment: Lots of google hits for ui/ti/welcompage, the Google productforums especially.  They all speak Italian, hard to read.  Since you live in Rome you ought to have a better shot at it :)  But probably fair to conclude that your home town and the language used in the forums can't be a coincidence.

Comment: @Will win98 SE, I hope. It's important to stay up to date!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Blame cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

This is a problem related to cache, your modem (ALICE, Telecom Italia) when not connect to internet will redirect all calls to `ui/ti/welcomePage`, you probably tried to access https://stackoverflow.com/ when modem was not connected to internet and now your browser thinks it should redirect to `ui/ti/welcomePage`

**Solution:** clear cache!

Comment: And blame Telecom Italia for issuing a permanent redirect instead of a temporary redirect.

Comment: This is what I get having to work on 4 different offices with 4 different APs every week. I will make a script which redirects to [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) whenever something of unpredictable happens on my computer